# What purpose does this ppa file in sources.d serve and why did they create errors on apt-get update?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

Earlier, I was getting the following error when execuing `apt-get update`:

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deb/dists/http/ppa/ubuntu/main/binary-i386/Packages  
404  Not Found
```

I found the corresponding deb-src inside the file `deb_http-ppa-precise.list` within `/ect/apt/sources.d/` containing the lines

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deb http/ppa/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deb http/ppa/ubuntu precise main
```

Upon commenting out those lines, `apt-get update` ran without any reported errors.

I'm curious as to why these particular lines were the cause for the reported errors on update, and are the packages linked to that ppa important?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those lines are causing the errors. They do not make any sense all and may be the result of a copy&paste error or something similar.

Just remove the whole file.